# Facebook Malformed access token error 190

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to setup this basic uploaded which allows a user to upload a video directly to my Facebook group but I'm having a problem with the user access token, its throwing back a error "Malformed access token"

I grabbed a user access token from the Facebook graph api explorer and hard coded it into the URL and everything worked fine

I have the slightest idea as to what the problem might be

MY CODE:

```
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "http://DOMAIN/post.php";
$video_title = "TITLE FOR THE VIDEO";
$video_desc = "DESCRIPTION FOR THE VIDEO";
$group_id = "GROUP";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

echo '<html><body>';

if(empty($code)) {
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
     . "&scope=publish_actions";
    echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/".$group_id."/videos?access_token=".$code."&"."title=".$video_title."&description=".$video_desc;

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
     method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';

echo '</body></html>';
```

THE ERROR IS:

```
 {
   "error": {
      "message": "Malformed access token AQDDR2mYCEP3F4MvRoBbHBhNViCPkdBhYu0IFyD3pkopzmIZlug69tzb3Cl7E1Z_5qzMTPBAnzMREGm0hU9Nym3EaIMCBelwhKOLwxSTQwStbZ7euPOxPLrfi9-JYSnJcjvy3K_13Ov14IaybzXfXhjNHLzZNuyofnFPbLVieYvOjfpT9UJSzS9TB6Plttbt0O4aKtnG9RkTaoNkJkwUgCw9IGV_dWw5vF77CrhyGxJ5B7quOZPjz39f5QtJ50X5njZE2C4jysMhg1Xfdg9vAhfaFYYEg4f_WrxVfF2QnHINHLLfhFbzSW74jJnEBoVszseA46nqWG4mnrgrs9K97jQ0iqc0UnCEY1JU92D94fX_kw",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "DCS2/KjriCI"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the access token and placed it in the post url and everything is working now

```
$app_id = "[APP_ID]";
$app_secret = "[APP_SECRET]";
$my_url = "[URL_TO_THIS_SCRIPT";
//$video_title = "TITLE FOR THE VIDEO";
//$video_desc = "DESCRIPTION FOR THE VIDEO";
$group_id = "[GROUP_OR_PAGE_ID]";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

echo '<html><body>';

if(empty($code)) {
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
     . "&scope=publish_actions";
    echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$access_token_Clean = strtr ($access_token, array ('{"access_token":"' => '', '","token_type":"bearer"}' => ''));





$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$group_id."/photos?access_token=".$access_token_Clean;

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
     method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file" accept="image/*">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';

echo '</body></html>';
```